# Delete / Hide / Remove Actionbar

Tags: android

I read about 20 topics and still didn't find a solution that worked for me.

I need to delete, hide, or remove the actionbar in my all activities.

Styles.xml (I tried Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar and many, many more):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

</style>
```

Dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
compile 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.5'
compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.1"
}
```

Only Theme.AppCompat works (with actionbar), others shut down the application on start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Setting activity theme in manifest

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  ....>
```

or you can define your custom theme in `styles.xml` and set theme to your activity.

```
    <style name="AppTheme.FullScreen"          
    parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorControlNormal</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorControlActivated</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorControlHighlight</item>

</style>
```

and use this theme.

```
    <activity android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FullScreen"
                  ....>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use theme in application tag in android manifest file. Here is the code:

```
application
    android:name=".MyCustomApplicationClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/m"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: unfortunately this shut down app at start (even when I change in styles on Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar or Theme.AppCompat )

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to achieve it.
1. Add this in **res/values/styles.xml** :

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and then set it as your activity's theme in Manifest:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" ... />
```

2. Programmatically:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Or,

```
  ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); OR getSupportActionBar();
  actionBar.hide();
```

Or,

```
getSupportActionBar().hide(); / getActionBar().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`  or `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">`

Comment: If I change this in styles.xml - 1. (light) Application shutdown on start, 2. (dark) "cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: Sorry my bad. I was on mobile. Dark is not needed. And btw, did you extend your activity class from AppCompatActivity?